# Increase column value by one based on condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I created a script that scrapes NBA play-by-play data and organizes it into a pandas dataframe. At the end of each quarter and the end of the game, the below values are shown in the 'Detail' column:

```
    Detail
End of the 1st Quarter  
End of the 2nd Quarter  
End of the 3rd Quarter  
End of the 4th Quarter  
End of Game
```

Is there a way to create a 'Quarter' column that starts with the number 1, then increases by 1 after the end of each quarter by using the 'Detail' Column? For example:

```
Detail           Quarter
Shot by...          1
Rebound...          1
End of 1st Quarter  1
Pass to...          2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a boolean with `cumsum` and `bfill`

```
import numpy as np
df['Quarter'] = np.where(
              df['Detail'].str.contains('Quarter'),
                             df['Detail'].str.contains('Quarter').cumsum(), 
                             np.nan
                       )

df['Quarter'] = df['Quarter'].bfill()
```

---

```
print(df)
   Detail               Quarter
0  Shot by...              1.0
1  Rebound...              1.0
2  End of 1st Quarter      1.0
3  Pass to...              2.0
4  Shot by...              2.0
5  Rebound...              2.0
6  End of 2nd Quarter      2.0
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for most games I ran the script on, but I did notice that games with overtime ended up having a NaN value. I replaced both of the str.contains('Quarter') to str.contains('End') so that the number of instances where "End" is seen is counted. This allowed overtime(s) to be counted as an extra quarter (5 or more depending on the number of overtimes).

Comment: @theroundaboot great initiative my friend, don't forget to accept the question :)